# Solve $2a_{n-2} = a_n + a_{n-1}$ using generating function

Tags: generating-functions

Need to solve:

$$2a_{n-2} = a_n + a_{n-1}$$

with: $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1=1$

I get:

$$f(x) = \frac{2x^3-x^2-x}{2x^2-x-1}$$ so I tried to scompose the denominator and I get:

$$f(x) = \frac{2x^3-x^2-x}{(x-1)(x+\frac{1}{2})}$$ now I think I have to use partial fraction but in this case I do not see any $x^3$ coming out so how should I procede?

$$\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: It should be one more term: $+(ax+b)$

Comment: why one more? could you please explain or link a source? I've some problem to understand how to use this procedure

Comment: See the example 2 of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). If you still cannot understand, try the "long division" link in that page.

Comment: How did you obtain that generating function? I have $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x-2x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you committed a typo in calculations. From:
$$a_n=2a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}$$
we should have:
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}\color{blue}{a_{n}}x^{n}=
x+\sum\limits_{n=2}a_nx^n=
x+\sum\limits_{n=2}\left(2a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}\right)x^n=\\
x+2x^2\left(\sum\limits_{n=2}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}\right)-x\left(\sum\limits_{n=2}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right)=\\
x+2x^2\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}\right)-x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n}x^{n}\right)=x+2x^2f(x)-xf(x)$$
and
$$\color{red}{f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x-2x^2}}=\frac{1}{3(1-x)}-\frac{1}{3(1+2x)}=\\
\sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{1}{3}x^n-\sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{1}{3}(-2)^nx^n=
\sum\limits_{n=0}\color{blue}{\frac{1-(-2)^n}{3}}x^n$$
and (also agrees with [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%3D2*a%5Bn-2%5D-a_%5Bn-1%5D,%20a%5B0%5D%3D0,%20a%5B1%5D%3D1))
$$a_n=\frac{1-(-2)^n}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the factorisation of the denominator. You should get
$$f(x) = \frac{2x^3-x^2-x}{(x-1)(2x+1)}.$$
Now this isn't a `proper` rational function (i.e. the degree of the numerator is not $<$ degree of the denominator). So (in theory) you have to perform the Euclidean division of the numerator by the denominator first.

However, observe that
$2x^3-x^2-x=x(2x^2-x-1)$,
so the ‘fraction’ simplifies to $\color{red}x$.